# Toggle Div outside of Current Div

Tags: jquery, css, html, drop-down-menu

Currently I have a toggle option attached to an *li* element. However I cannot seem to display the div that is toggled outside of the *li* parent div.

```
<div id="header">
    <header>
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li class="action" data-content="#content1">2</li>
        </ul>
    </header>
</div>
<div class="content" id="content1">
    <p>A Bunch of Content</p>
</div>
```

To save space here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Thelawman/9KCg9/
When I do this I can see a top portion of the toggled *div* inside the *header*. I want to display it directly under the *header* element.
Thanks in advance, the people here are always incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is because of `position:fixed` which you are using for `div#header`. Try this:

```
#header {
    overflow:hidden;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:66px;
    z-index:1;
    background-color:#000000;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/9KCg9/2/)**

or

If you want to use `position:fixed` to stay header fixed at the top as you scrolled the page. You can use `margin-top` to `div.content`. Try this:

```
.content {
    display:none;
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#FF000D;
    border: 4px solid;
    margin-top:68px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/9KCg9/3/)

Comment: I was hoping to have my #header to stay fixed at the top as I scrolled the page. Can I not have both the toggle div and a header that stays fixed at the top of the screen?